Vegetation and climate change
The only system that converts Co2 into O2 is vegetation. We have been slowly destroying this over many years by pulling down trees and covering vegetation with development. Are we putting more Co2 into to the atmosphere or destroying the only thing that can make the conversion. I appreciate the fact that once a tree dies that it adds Co2. Should  we not be planting trees to counteract our activities and not only replace but have more as a safeguard. I don’t believe that fossil fuel is the only problem. Secondly, is Mother Nature trying to fix the imbalance by creating a green house effect to bring vegetation back to the level that’s required, after all that is what it has done for billions of years.
